# Random assignment to a specific percentage of observations in SAS

Tags: sas, statistics

The question below is what I am trying to figure out. I tried using a proc surveyselect but I am not sure if there is a way to assign random numbers to more than just 2 groups since here I need to randomly assign 5 groups.

Question) There are 5 different inspectors who will be assigned to investigate the accidents.

Inspector #1 and Inspector #2 should each be randomly assigned to inspect 20% of the total accidents.

Inspector #3 and Inspector # 4 should each be randomly assigned to inspect 15% of the total accidents.

Inspector #5 should be assigned to inspect 30% of accidents.

Write code that randomly assigns about the required percentage of accidents. Note that the percentage assigned to each inspector does not have to be the exact percentage, but should be fairly close to the required percentage. Note that ‘randomly assigned’ implies that each accident will have the same percentage probability of assignment to inspector as every other accident.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `TABLE` method of the `RAND()` function.

```
data want ;
  inspector = rand('table',.2,.2,.15,.15,.30);
  set sashelp.cars;
run;
```

To check the distribution look at the frequencies of the new variable.

```
proc freq data=want;
  tables inspector;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SAMPRATE option in PROC SURVEYSELECT.

```
/*create rates for sampling requirement*/
data rates;
infile cards dlm="," dsd;
input Origin $ _rate_;
cards;
Asia, 0.3
Europe,  0.2
USA, 0.5
;;;;
run;


/*sort data by strata variable*/
proc sort data=sashelp.cars out=cars;
by origin;
run;

/*verify percentages ahead of time*/
proc freq data=cars;
table origin;
run;

/*Random selection*/
proc surveyselect data=cars method=srs samprate=rates out=want seed=123456;
strata origin;
run;

/*check results*/
proc freq data=want;
table origin;
run;
```